# react-table change row color on cell input event

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have a react table that has multiple columns. One on the column cells has an input box. I'm trying to change the color of the complete row when a user input is triggered for row associated with the input box

I have tried setting the background style returned from `getTrProps` return style background: someState but the color only seems to be set when the table is loaded.

```
function Table(props) {

  const headers = [
    { Header: name, accessor: 'name' },
    { Header: title: accessor: 'title', Cell: TitleCell },
  ];

  return (
    <ReactTable PaginationComponent={PaginationBar}
      data={data}
      columns={headers}
      ...
      getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
        if (rowInfo && rowInfo.row) {
          return {
            style: {
              background: someState,
            }
          } 
        } else {
          return {}
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}

function TitleCell(props) {

    const doSomthing = () => {
        return something
    }

    return (
        <Form.Group as={Col}>
            <InputGroup>
                <Form.Control 
                    key={Math.random()}                    
                    defaultValue={props.value}
                    onChange={(e) => {                                                                                                                 
                        doSomthing(e.target.value);                           
                    }}
                />
            </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you create codesandbox or jsfiddle ?

Comment: Hey Shubhanu. I haven't really used the above tools yet. Ill try and setup a table there and get a working example

Comment: Cool That way i would be able to solve your problem real quick

Comment: https://codepen.io/RojerC/pen/qedyZO

Comment: Hey, Iv added an example react table with an input box cell. The row color is currently red, if a value is entered into a rows input I need that row to change to blue

Comment: Cool i'll try to solve your problem.